# How do I calculate two DataGrid columns and show the result in a third column in WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which has Bindings to a XMLDataProvider. I want the Column "Hours" to show the Time difference between the column "Begin" and "End".

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <DataGrid Name="workinghours" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=WorkTime}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource columnHeaderStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Day}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Begin" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Begin}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="End" Binding="{Binding XPath=@End}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hours" Binding="{Binding Converter={local:HourConverter}}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

I tried to use a IValueConverter, get the the Times, put the into some Date Class, calculate the difference and return the result. Unfortunately I can't even get the data.

```
 public class HourConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return 0;

        var xml = value as IEnumerable<XmlNode>;
        var von = xml.Select(x => x.Attributes["Begin"].Value);
        var bis = xml.Select(x => x.Attributes["End"].Value);
        // save into some date object, calculate the hours between, return the amount

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Edit:

Thanks for all answers!

I got it to work. I forgot that when I only get one Object, I don't need to (can't) save the value as Enumerable < XmlNode > but only as XmlNode. I then get the values with xml.Attributes["Begin"].innerText as String, split it by ':' (the times are saved like hh:mm), parse it into a new Timespan and return (timespan2 - timespan1).toString().

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return 0;

        var xml = value as XmlNode;
        var von = xml.Attributes["Begin"].InnerText;
        var bis = xml.Attributes["End"].InnerText;
        string[] ar1 = von.Split(':');
        string[] ar2 = bis.Split(':');
        TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(Int32.Parse(ar1[0]), Int32.Parse(ar1[1]), 0);
        TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(Int32.Parse(ar2[0]), Int32.Parse(ar2[1]), 0);


        return (t2 - t1).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
    }
```

Comment: What means " I can't even get the data"? - did you tried to debug the Converter?

Comment: Actually, I get a NullPointerException when i build the project like this. I have little experience with WPF and have seen a project where someone used the IValueConverter to get the data of other columns.

Comment: Try to place a breakpoint to the convert method and find out where the exception is thrown

Comment: have you registered the converter as resource? this is stack documentation page for converters, there working are examples: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wpf/3950/value-and-multivalue-converters#t=201702081456560034602 Also, maybe IMultiValueConverter will be simpler in your case.

Comment: the first xml.Select throws the exception. value contains {Element, Name="WorkTime"} which should be right, var xml stays null.

Comment: Thanks @Arie , I will read into that.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to bind a resources with the link to your converter:

```
<Page
    xmlns:converterPath="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyNamespace"
<Page.Resources>
    <converterPath:HourConverter x:Key="hourConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Then you have to bind the converter and a parameter :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Hours" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource hourConverter}}" />
```

Finally, in the converter you are returning `null` you have to return the formated value you want to display